# pyqt5 connecting button press to a stackedWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-signals

I just converted my .ui file into the py file and tried to link a `QPushButton` to a `QStackedWidget` using the signals and slots system. This is what I attempted to do:

```
self.createButton.clicked.connect(self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(2))
```

and it was supposed to set the index of the stacked widget to 2 on button click. However at runtime the following error occurred:

```
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

Was not really sure what argument 1 was, but the placeholder code of:

```
self.createButton.clicked.connect(self.stackedWidget.update)
```

seemed to work except that was not what I want to achieve. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did a bit more experimenting and it seems like `setCurrentIndex` cannot be used as a function with the brackets, but how do I pass what index I want into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the the connect function takes as a parameter a function to call when the click event is emited so you should wrap your statment in a lambda function as follows :

```py
self.createButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(2))
```